# Building a script to run a cmd as a different user

Tags: batch-file

I would like to build a script that runs at startup. This script would start a service, but it has to be ran as an admin acct (mine)

Run as jbickford with password xxxxxx (I need the script to save my credentials)
Net Start MorphoManager (This is the service name)

How would I write the first part?

Comment: Have you looked into Task Scheduler? It can do this very easily without you having to write a script.

Comment: @Confuzing has you on the right path.  When you create the task you can enter in your credentials to run the task as any user on the system.

Comment: Why don't you set the service to start automatically when the computer starts up?